# Summing columns in the Database instead of an ActiveRecord method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

The `LaborHours` model uses a `total_hours` method to tally up a year's worth of hours. Validation ensures that `total_hours` is greater than zero. This all works just fine in the application. I understand that this data is not normalized, but I'm okay with that for now because it makes some of the dynamic forms more convenient to build.

We are using Postgresql but might be mandated to migrate to another database at some future date, so portability is an issue.

In another question that I asked where I posted this model, a commentor stated that it was 'a waste' to do the sum in this way, and that the summation could more efficiently and effectively done in the database. He did not elaborate out of respect for the scope of the original question, so...

Without raw SQL, what is 'The Rails Way™' to efficiently perform this summation in the database, that also allows for record validation both in the database and in the ActiveRecord model that the sum is greater than zero?

LaborHours Model:

```
class LaborHours < ActiveRecord::Base
  nilify_blanks

  belongs_to :positions_task
  belongs_to :year

  has_one :proposal, :through => :positions_task
  has_many :valid_years, :through => :proposal, :source => :years

  validates :year, :positions_task, :presence => true
  validates :total_hours, :numericality => {:greater_than => 0}

  def total_hours
    m1.to_i + m2.to_i + m3.to_i + m4.to_i + m5.to_i + m6.to_i + m7.to_i + m8.to_i + m9.to_i + m10.to_i + m11.to_i + m12.to_i
  end
end
```

The labor_hours excerpt from schema.db:

```
  create_table "labor_hours", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "positions_task_id"
    t.integer  "year_id"
    t.string   "description"
    t.integer  "m1"
    t.integer  "m2"
    t.integer  "m3"
    t.integer  "m4"
    t.integer  "m5"
    t.integer  "m6"
    t.integer  "m7"
    t.integer  "m8"
    t.integer  "m9"
    t.integer  "m10"
    t.integer  "m11"
    t.integer  "m12"
    t.integer  "position_task_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",        null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",        null: false
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that you should rather reorganise your database to have a `LaborYear` and `LaborMonth`. Having 12 separate fields for months seems to be needless duplication. So have:

```
class LabourYear < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :labor_months
end


class LabourMonth < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :labor_year
end
```

This way you can simply ask:

`LaborYear.find_by(year: '2015').labor_months.pluck(:hours).inject(:+)`

Comment: then you can do `LaborYear.find_by(year: '2015').labor_months.sum(:hours)`

Comment: If there was simply a date in the labour months table, maybe represented by the first day of the month, then you could: LaborMonth.where(:month_date => Date.parse("2014-01-01")..Date.parse("2014-12-01")).sum(:hours) This would be more flexible, in that you could easily do non-calendar years: LaborMonth.where(:month_date => Date.parse("2014-04-01")..Date.parse("2015-03-01")).sum(:hours)

Comment: Fair enough. That would normalize the data, but is there a way to do it with the tables that exist?